# Can't use SCD component because of identity column

Tags: ssis, etl, scd

I have a fact table and a dimension table. dimension table uses identity as id column and that id is in the fact table for relation.
In the ssis, scd component doesn't see my id row on dimension as business key, how can i do scd, what should i do?

My fact table:
[image]

My dimension table:

[image]

SSIS:
[image]

Comment: Can you describe how to use SCD, I believe SCD not conflict with identity

Comment: Is country_id the PK on the dimension table? If it is then that’s probably your issue. You need to have a surrogate key as your PK and then you can use country_id as your BK. Unfortunately, this also means you’d have to redesign/rebuild your data warehouse to use surrogate keys before you could implement SCD

Comment: after these questions, i thinked and fixed the problem. I added an id column to dimension table. thank you...